# Is there a way to enforce a unique column using doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I know I can always set a unique DB key using MYSQL schema however was just curious if ORM's like doctrine allowed you to set a column to be unique in code?

For example how can I make it in code so that username's are unique in code at run time?

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

```php
<?php

function insert_user($username,$email,$password) 
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($username); //HOW CAN I MAKE THIS UNIQUE IN CODE?
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setPassword($password);

    try {
        //save to database
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    catch(Exception $err) {
        die($err->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you want?

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint

Since I don't have your code I can't give you a practical example.

Comment: It's the table schema you need to change, look at the documentation I linked to... uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="myname", columns={"username"}) would probably be what you want to add in your case.

Comment: this is a better answer as it works in more circumstances

Comment: Could you please update the link? Here is the current one (2.7) https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_uniqueconstraint

Answer (score 78):

Just providing an alternate solution that is a little simpler.

If it is a single column, you could simply add a unique on the column definition:

```
class User
{
   /**
    * @Column(name="username", length=300, unique=true)
    */
   protected $username;
}
```

Documentation on this:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column

If you need a unique index on multiple columns, you still need to use the method Andreas provided.

note: I'm not sure since which version this is available. It might be this was not yet available in 2011.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the uniq constraints in the **@Table** declaration

> **@UniqueConstraint**
>
> Annotation is used inside the @Table annotation on the entity-class
>   level. It allows to hint the SchemaTool to generate a database unique
>   constraint on the specified table columns. It only has meaning in the
>   SchemaTool schema generation context.
>
> **Required attributes**: 
>   *name*: Name of the Index,
>   *columns*: Array of columns.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="username_uniq", columns={"username"})})
 */
class User
{
   /**
    * @Column(name="username", length=300)
    */
   protected $username;
}
```

source: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint